# This is a Warning Occurred in my application. What's it Mean?

Tags: c#

**CA1001:** Types that own disposable fields should be disposable   Implement IDisposable on 'ruleSet' because it creates members of the following IDisposable types: 'FileSystemWatcher'. If 'ruleSet' has previously shipped, adding new members that implement IDisposable to this type is considered a breaking change to existing consumers.   Representation  ruleSet.cs  14

Comment: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182172.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182172.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CA1001 Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis warning. What does it mean ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164592/ca1001-visual-studio-2012-code-analysis-warning-what-does-it-mean)

Answer (score 2):

That means that if your type (class) contains fields, properties, or any sort of reference to another type that implements the `IDisposable` interface, then your type should be `IDisposable` as well.  So you can do something like this.

```
public class MyType : IDisposable {
    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    public void Dispose() {
       if(_watcher != null)
          _watcher.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then be sure when you are using your type (MyType in this case) you are wrapping it in a using statement as such:

```
using(var t = new MyType()) {

}
```

That way the `Dispose()` method will be called automatically when the block completes.